# group data based on user specified group

Tags: r, split, shiny, ggvis

I have a shiny app that accepts user input for which x and y variable to plot and has the ability to filter it also based on user input.

[image: Image of app seen here]What I want to be able to do is group the data based on a user specified group (only species is listed in the sample, but my actual code will use many different inputs to group by, with multiple = FALSE), and have the data adjust so that it takes the mean of each unique user specified group and plots the results.  So in this example, there would only be 3 data points displayed, one for each species in the iris data set.  Taking specifically the setosa species with the hypothetical user input of x=Petal.Length and y=Petal.Width, the data point would be plotted at x=mean of setosa Petal.Lengths and y=mean of setosa Petal.Widths.  I ran it with the basic R plot function and this is what I want it to look like as a result in ggvis:

[image: Desired Result Image]

This was accomplished with the following code conducted in a separate script:

```
alldata <- as.data.frame(iris)


splitDataX <- split(alldata$`Petal.Length`, alldata$`Species`, drop = FALSE)
meanXvar <- lapply(splitDataX, mean)

splitDataY <- split(alldata$`Petal.Width`, alldata$`Species`, drop = FALSE)
meanYvar <- lapply(splitDataY, mean)

plot(meanXvar, meanYvar)
```

As I have it now, the app crashes when I attempt to group the species data by the mean of each x and y variable.  The else section works as intended if it stands alone.

```
# GLOBAL

#Check packages to use in library
library('shiny') #allows for the shiny app to be used
library('stringr') #string opperator
library('ggvis') #allows for interactive ploting
library('dplyr')

alldata <- iris

#Establish options for drop down menus
specieschoices <- unique(as.character(alldata$Species))
petalwchoices <- unique(as.character(alldata$Petal.Width))
petallchoices <- unique(as.character(alldata$Petal.Length))
sepallchoices <- unique(as.character(alldata$Sepal.Length))
sepalwchoices <- unique(as.character(alldata$Sepal.Width))

# UI

ui<-fluidPage(
titlePanel("Explorer"),
fluidRow(
column(4,
       wellPanel(
         h4("Apply Filters"),
         selectInput(inputId = "species", label="Select a Species:", choices = sort(specieschoices), selected=specieschoices, multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE),
         selectInput(inputId = "petalw", label="Select Petal Width:", choices = sort(petalwchoices), selected=petalwchoices, multiple = TRUE, selectize = FALSE),
         selectInput(inputId = "petall", label="Select Petal Length", choices = sort(petallchoices), selected=petallchoices, multiple = TRUE, selectize = FALSE),
         selectInput(inputId = "sepall", label="Select Sepal Length", choices = sort(sepallchoices), selected=sepallchoices, multiple = TRUE, selectize = FALSE),
         selectInput(inputId = "sepalw", label="Select Sepal Width", choices = sort(sepalwchoices), selected=sepalwchoices, multiple = TRUE, selectize = FALSE),
         checkboxInput(inputId = "groupdata", label="Group Data for Mean Analysis", value = FALSE),
         conditionalPanel(
           condition = "input.groupdata == true",
           wellPanel(
             selectInput(inputId = "group", label = "Select Filter to Group By", choices = as.character("Species"), selected = "Species", multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE)
           ))
       )),
column(8,
       ggvisOutput("plot1")
),
column(4,
       wellPanel(
         h4("Data Variables"),
         selectInput(inputId = "x", label="Select x-axis Variable:", choices=as.character(names(alldata[,1:4])),selected='Petal.Length', multiple = FALSE),
         selectInput(inputId = "y", label="Select y-axis Variable:", choices=as.character(names(alldata[,1:4])),selected='Petal.Width', multiple = FALSE)
       ))
))

#SERVER
server<-function(input,output,session)
{

#Set up reactive variables
filteredData <- reactive({

#Apply filters
m <- alldata %>% filter(
  `Species` %in% input$species,
  `Petal.Width` %in% input$petalw,
  `Petal.Length` %in% input$petall,
  `Sepal.Width` %in% input$sepalw,
  `Sepal.Length` %in% input$sepall
)
m <- droplevels(as.data.frame(m))
m
})

vis <- reactive({

################## THIS IS THE SECTION THAT I NEED HELP WITH #################
if (input$groupdata == TRUE) {
  splitDataX <- split(input$x %>% filteredData(), input$group %>% alldata, drop = FALSE)
  meanXvar <- lapply(splitDataX, mean)
  xvar <- prop("x", as.symbol(meanXvar))

  splitDataY <- split(input$y %>% filteredData(), input$group %>% alldata, drop = FALSE)
  meanYvar <- lapply(splitDataY, mean)
  yvar <- prop("y", as.symbol(meanYvar))
}

else {
  xvar <- prop("x", as.symbol(input$x))
  yvar <- prop("y", as.symbol(input$y))
}
##############################################################################

#Plot Data with Visualization Customization
p1 = filteredData() %>%
  ggvis(x = xvar, y = yvar) %>%
  layer_points(size.hover := 200,
               fillOpacity:= 0.5, fillOpacity.hover := 1,
               fill = ~Species
  ) %>%

  #Specifies the size of the plot
  set_options(width = 800, height = 450, duration = 0)

})

#Actually plots the data
vis %>% bind_shiny("plot1")
}

#Run the Shiny App to Display Webpage
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: It would help if you could show examples along the way of what your talking about and an example of your desired result.

Comment: I have added an image of the program that will pop up if the code is run, however, I am not sure how to show an example of what my desired result would look like which is why I described it as explicitly as I could in the question.

Comment: Thanks. You could probably show it in R with the same built-in dataset without using Shiny (give some hypothetical user input).

Comment: So if I'm reading this correctly `yvar` and `xvar` aren't actually in `filteredData()`?  I agree with @Hack-R, maybe step back from shiny for a minute and think about how you would go about calculating and graphing the means of each group within the `ggvis` framework.  Once you have that worked out, add the shiny complication.

Comment: @aosmith that is correct it is within vis but not within filteredData.  I have edited my post to reflect your suggestion

Comment: @Hack-R I have edited my post to reflect your suggestion

Comment: @aosmith do you have any suggestion on how to solve this issue now that I have implemented your suggestion?

Comment: @Hack-R do you have any suggestion on how to solve this issue now that I have implemented your suggestion?

Comment: I had suggested showing an attempt to plots the means of each group using `ggvis` outside of shiny, not `plot`.  As `ggvis` works primarily with data.frames, trying to give it a list may not work.  Given that, I would probably focus on figuring out how to make a summarized dataset by group.